# "Merged" dependency and constituency tree

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I am working on a research in which I use the `CoreNlp` in order to parse sentences, using the various available annotators (mainly, constituency and sentiment).

I am now trying to create a "merged" trees which include both constituency and dependency information from which I am going to extract grammar (can think about PCFG).

I am trying to get to something like the left trees in the image:

[image: trees]
(image from [Relational-Realizational Parsing (Tsarfaty and Sima’an, 2008)](http://www.tsarfaty.com/pdfs/coling08.pdf))

Is there some "easy" way to work with the provided parser outputs (in code that is) to get to something like that?

Alternatively, is there any implementation you may know of based on the Stanford NLP library?

Would `GrammaticalStructure` be helpful here? Does making a GS for each node and reading it's `typedDependencies()` at each constituency node make sense here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a "snippet" (quite a lengthy one) for the code required to create a merged constituency and dependency tree which goes along the lines suggested above - traversing both trees.

[Merge Constituency and Dependency](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tcagan/bnkpe)

The process in high level:

1. Get the constituency tree using parser/pipeline
2. Get grammatical structure of the tree and from it, typed dependencies (note - keeping punctuation)
3. Convert the typed dependencies into a dependency tree
4. Merge the dependency and constituency trees based on the matching node coverage spans.

The code (classes):

- `DependencySpan` - represents a span and the nodes covering it (used for matching spans)
- `DependencyTreeNode` - a node in dependency tree which holds reference to a core label (which in turn, has a related word index used for getting a span)
- `MergedNode` - a merged constituency + dependency node.
- `MergeConstituencyAndDependency` - actual code to merge trees - works along the lines of algorithm above. Include the main (entry point for testing).

One thing I am not 100% sure of is why the "sentiment" annotator is required - without it creating the grammatical structure throws an error.

**A disclaimer** - I am not proficient with the Stanford NLP library and all it's options. The code is loosely based on other examples I've found online and there could be better ways of doing this task.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of some code for working with the constituency and dependency parses.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("annotators","tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
String sampleDoc = "This is the first sentence.  This is the second one.";
Annotation annotation = new Annotation(sampleDoc);
pipeline.annotate(annotation);
List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
  Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
  SemanticGraph deps = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
}
```

For your project you're going to need to study these two classes:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html

http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html

The Tree class represents the constituency parse and the SemanticGraph class represents the dependency parse.

Comment: thanks - I was actually familiar with these classes and wanted to know if there was a "built-in" way of merging them or some sample code I could use. I ended up implementing an algorithm to do this merge based on the two classes and an intermediary node format I created. I will try to answer with my code soon.